# Not able to handle the dropdown selection in reporting

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to modify below code of reporting. This is used for reporting in selenium on the basis of commands used in script(e.g.: click on checkbox, image, radio button etc). It is throwing the exception when selenium script have "Select" class to handle the dropdownn. Can you please help me to modify below code to handle dropdown selection in reporting part.

```
public void click(){
    String name = ""; String strObjectType = "";

    if(this.globalObject.webElementCondition==true){

        if (this.getAttribute("type")!=null && (this.getAttribute("type").equalsIgnoreCase("submit")|| this.getAttribute("type").equalsIgnoreCase("button"))){
          name=this.getAttribute("value");
          if (name.trim().equals("")) {
              name=this.getText();
          }          
          strObjectType = "button";
        }else if (this.getTagName().equalsIgnoreCase("a")){
          name=this.getText();
          strObjectType = "hyperlink";
        }else if (this.getTagName().equalsIgnoreCase("img")){
          //name=this.getAttribute("src");
          String[] ImgName = this.getAttribute("src").split("/");
          name = ImgName[ImgName.length-1];
          strObjectType = "Image link";
        }else if (this.getAttribute("name")!=null&&!this.getAttribute("name").equals("")){
          name=this.getAttribute("name");
          strObjectType = "text/lable";
        }else if (this.getAttribute("id")!=null&&!this.getAttribute("id").equals("")){
              name=this.getAttribute("id");
        }else if (this.getAttribute("value")!=null&&!this.getAttribute("value").equals("")){
          name=this.getAttribute("value"); 
        } 
        //System.out.println("Name : "+name);
        try
        {   
            execute(DriverCommand.CLICK_ELEMENT, ImmutableMap.of("id", id));

            this.globalObject.reporting.WriteStep("Pass", "Click on ["+name+"] "+ strObjectType , "User should be able to click on ["+name+"] "+ strObjectType, "Clicked on ["+name+"] " + strObjectType);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {   this.globalObject.TestStepStatus="Fail";
            this.globalObject.reporting.WriteStep("Fail", "Click on ["+name+"] "+ strObjectType , "User should be able to click on ["+name+"] " + strObjectType, "Not Clicked on ["+name+"] "+ strObjectType);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: I don't know why you have this `method` written this way. But, this is extremely bad way to handle this scenario for sure, at least in `Selenium`. There are lot BETTER and EASIER ways to handle clicks in `Selenium`

Comment: Where do you handle select in your method? Can you also provide the HTML?

Comment: In your provided code you have not used select anywhere. Anyhow if you need to click just check it by tagName for options, since any how in the end click is only performed over options.